# Changing classes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class

Im trying to change class in the same dive twice using this simple 2 sunctions:

```
  $('.q_one').click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('q_one').addClass('q_two');

  });



$('.q_two').click(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('q_two').addClass('q_three');

      });
```

So I was hoping this to work in the way, that when I click on .q_one the class will change to q_two, and the once It has a this class after click It will change it to q_three.

Unfortunately it works only on first example.

What do I do wrong please?

Comment: Where are you expecting the class to change - because you are using `$(this)`

Comment: I would like my html to do the following : <div class="q_one"></div> ->click-><div class="q_two"></div> ->click-><div class="q_three"></div>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the `q_two` doesn't exist when the handler is bound.

I'd put your classes in an Array, and cycle them by maintaining an index. I assume at the end you want to return to the first.

```
var classes = ['q_one','q_two','q_three'],
    i = 0;

$('.q_one').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass(classes[ i ])
           .addClass(classes[ i = ++i % classes.length ]);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JH9Ve/

Comment: +1 because on top of *the* solution you show, how we're always modifying the same element (formerly knwon as .q_one) regardless of classNames it might have later.

Comment: I already +1'd this, but won't this still not work with q_two?  Wouldn't you want something like: `$(document).on("click", "." + classes.join(",."), function() { ... `

Comment: I believe using the (old) `live` or (new) `on` methods are more friendly. I don't know which performance impact is related to them, but you'll leave the hard work for the library (which is why you're using one, isn't it?)

Comment: @AdamRackis: Well, check out the demo. ;-) Seriously though, you've got to remember that we're not adding new elements to the DOM. We're just changing the class on the existing element. I'm pretty sure that's what OP was trying to achieve. *"when I click on .q_one the class will change to q_two,"*. So there aren't any new elements beng added. Therefore the single handler will work. :)

Comment: @tyron: But where's the hard work? This is a simple way to cycle through an array. And if more classes need to be added to the cycle, the only thing to change will be the Array.

Comment: @amnotiam: well, if I want to do some different action inside the function, upon the class, this way you won't be able to achieve. take a look at this comparision: http://jsfiddle.net/NHmjM/1/ (your solution) x http://jsfiddle.net/DAcWB/1/ (mine)

Comment: @amnotiam: please, don't take me wrong. I know this was not originally the scope of the question, but I just want to assume the most generic use-case. I believe that, once the div has changed the class, it should behave as if it was always belonging to that class. This is only possible with `on` as `live`; with click, the function bounded to the element will always be the original.

Comment: @tyron: Yeah, there will always be up/downsides to any approach. To rewrite your example (using my approach), you could [do this instead](http://jsfiddle.net/NHmjM/3/). But each approach has its own overhead in some regard. Yours is higher maintenance if you want to add/change the list of classes. Whereas mine could end up requiring a separation of behavior into a switch statement, and possibly separate functions for clarity, if different behavior is indeed needed for each class. So it will certainly come down to the actual problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You gonna have to switch **'click'** to **'live'** or **'on'**

the problem is that the click event is not binded to the element with the new class 'q-two'

```
$(document).on('click', '.q_two', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('q_two').addClass('q_three');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the listeners to a parent element if you want to be able to handle clicks on elements that will be added int he future.

```
$(document).on('click', '.q_two', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('q_two').addClass('q_three');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change the class of your elements, the previous binding won't apply again if you're using `click()`.

Use `on` (on jQuery 1.7+) or `live` (previously).

```
$(document).on('click', '.q_one', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('q_one').addClass('q_two');
});

$(document).on('click', '.q_two', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('q_two').addClass('q_three');
});
```

Live:

```
$('.q_one').live('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('q_one').addClass('q_two');
});

$('.q_two').live('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('q_two').addClass('q_three');
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/XYKbL/4/

**UPDATE**:
I made a comparision from using the [technique I described](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrons/KmzPZ/) here and the [bounding to the `click`](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrons/sFqu9/) method (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8760231/891772)).